# Ошибка в Binding (XAML) заполнение ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Не могу вывести нормально Binding в ListView

```
<ListView

        Grid.RowSpan="2"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            Margin="0,37,0,0" 
            x:Name="ListOfFilters" 
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}"
            DataContext="{StaticResource FiltersViewModel}"
            SelectedIndex="0">
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBLock Text="{Binding Filters/Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <helpers:EffectListSelection />
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
```

Код C#, нужно чтобы в ListView отобразился только Title

```
public class FiltersViewModel:MainViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public FilterType Type { get; set; }

    private static List<FiltersViewModel> filters = new List<FiltersViewModel>
    {
        new FiltersViewModel() { Title = "Original", Type = FilterType.Original},
        new FiltersViewModel() { Title = "Antique", Type = FilterType.Antique},
    };
    public static List<FiltersViewModel> Filters => filters;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой хрустальный шар предполагает, что вы хотите вот что:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```